# I used disk utility to delete bootcamp. Now I cannot boot my partition for Mac OS

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

When I was repartitioning my Mac, I tried to use disk utility to completely delete my bootcamp partition as it was giving me issues. I had specified to make my SSD as just one partition using Disk Utility. Now I have to use internet recovery, and only my bootable USB having windows on it shows up. I would like to access my Mac OS data, as it still shows up under disk0s2.

Update 1::::

[image]

Comment: What is `disk02`? Did you mean `disk0s2`? You can help by posting the output from  `diskutil list disk0`, `fdisk /dev/disk0` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant diskos2

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my question with the output.

Comment: It looks like you have a Core Storage volume at disk0s2, Windows on disk0s3 and 4, and an APFS container (Apple's new file system) at disk0s5, but the Recovery system isn't recognizing the APFS container. APFS was sort-of added in 10.12 (Sierra), but wasn't all there until 10.13 (High Sierra). What version of Recovery are you running? Try `sw_vers` to find out. Also, what keys did you hold to start in Recovery? Command-Option-S (no Shift key!) should get you the latest version that'll work on your Mac.

Comment: It looks like it says I'm running the recovery that came with my Mac, version 10.8.5. When I tried to boot into recovery using Command Option S, it just continued to boot into my Windows partition. It's booting into internet recovery right now.

Comment: D'oh! That was a brain-o on my part, it should be Command-Option-R, not S.